# Deploying Out folder in NextJS 12.1.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Before the new version 12.1.0 of NextJS when i ran the command run build && export i would get this Out  folder, which I could upload to any host, for example Netlify and that would deploy my website without any more problems.

[Out folder before NextJS 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5TTj.png)

However, since then, when i exceute that command, i get this other version of the Out folder, which doesn't work the same when I upload it, and I don't really know how to solve it, because i need to update my project from Next JS 11 to 12 but this thing is avoiding me from it.

[Out folder after NextJS 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJzsW.png)

Comment: Your second image shows the `out/_next` folder contents, not the `out` folder.

Comment: Yes because inside the out folder it's just the _next folder, nothing else :s

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing the Image component from the 'next/image' with the standard html img tag.